# Google Apps Script : Insert x rows after every cells in range

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to add x blank rows after every no blank cells in a range.
I use a loop but with my loop, only the first cell is affected.

Here, my code : 
I think I know where I'm wrong (I need to loop in `sheet.insertRowsAfter(i, 5);` but I can not do it...)

Thank you !

```
function insertRows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("test");

  var sourceRange = sheet.getRange(10, 1, sheet.getLastRow());
  var sheetData = sourceRange.getValues();

  var numRows = sourceRange.getNumRows();
  Logger.log(numRows);

  for (var i=10; i < numRows; i++) {
    sheet.insertRowsAfter(i, 5);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share a sample sheet?  If I understand you correctly, you may have a range of, for example, rows 1-100 and maybe rows 20, 40 and 60 are blank so you want to add in this case 5 more blank rows after each of these.  If this is true recognize that when you add 5 rows after row 20 you have moved the other blank rows down by 5 making them in my example rows 45 and 65.

Comment: Sure ! This example : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JiTJbfTZpMRv3b1OTDmUp42yPvJclpr3ZVcMvERS2Gc/edit?usp=sharing

I have 10 rows, after every rows, I need to add 3 blank rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case we need to start at the end of the range and work our way up, adding rows where appropriate.  The code below will do this and add a 5 rows below any row which has data, even adding rows if there is a blank row following the one with data.  You could pass startRow to the function if you wish for more flexibility

```
function insertRows() {
  var startRow = 10;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("test");

  var sourceRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, sheet.getLastRow());
  var sheetData = sourceRange.getValues();

  var numRows = sourceRange.getNumRows() - startRow;
//  Logger.log(numRows);

  for (var i=numRows; i > -1; i--) {
    if (sheetData[i].join("")) {
      sheet.insertRowsAfter(i + startRow, 5);
    }
  }
}
```

As a general comment:  You are retrieving more rows as necessary as sheet.getLastRow() gets the last row number with data and the use in getRange() is telling the app to pull that number of rows as opposed to that number minus the starting position.

Comment: Work like a charm ^^

Answer (score 2):

Try the below. This will add 3 rows when there is a no blank cell.

```
function insertRows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("test");
  var sourceRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow());
  var sheetData = sourceRange.getValues();
  for (var i=0; i < sheetData.length; i++) {
    if(sheetData[i][0]!=""){
         sheet.insertRowsAfter(i+1, 3);
         sheetData = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
    }
  }
}
```